# Android sqlite store data from List<LocalDate>

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jodatime

I'm trying to store each data as each rows on the database. I managed to store the data but it is being stored as one row for all the data. Btw, I'm using `import org.joda.time.LocalDate`

Result I'm getting is:

```
|tbl_id | days                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1      | 2016-9-10, 2016-9-11, 2016-9-12 2016-9-13, 2016-9-14, 2016-9-15, 2016-9-16, 2016-9-17, 2016-9-18, 2016-9-19, 2016-9-20
```

What im after is

```
|tbl_id | days                                                          
-------------------
|1      | 2016-9-10
|2      | 2016-9-11
|3      | 2016-9-12
```

Here's what i have so far

method days

```
 String from = "2016-9-10";
    String to = "2016-9-20";

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

                try {

                    String reformatDateFrom = myFormat.format(df.parse(from));
                    String reformatDateTo = myFormat.format(df.parse(to));
                    LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(reformatDateFrom);
                    LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(reformatDateTo);
                    List<LocalDate> days= new ArrayList<>();

                    while (!start.isAfter(end)) {
                        days.add(start);
                        start = start.plusDays(1);

                    }

                    Toast.makeText(this, "This" + days,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    databaseHandler.insertDays(days);
                } catch (ParseException pe) {
                    pe.printStackTrace();
                }
```

method insert

```
public void insertDays(List<LocalDate> days) {
            int size = days.size();

            sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(KEY_DAYS, String.valueOf(days.get(i)));
                    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_DAYS, null, contentValues);
                }
                sqLiteDatabase.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
               sqLiteDatabase.close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What method contains the first code snippet? Please edit your question to show this.

Comment: The `insertDays()` method looks (mostly) correct. (One issue unrelated to your question is that you should close the database in a `finally` clause.) When do you call this `insertDays()` method?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I call it after while loop inside method days. `databaseHandler.insertDays(String.valueOf(days)); `

Comment: `databaseHandler.insertDays(String.valueOf(days));` This calls a different `insertDays()` method which takes a `String` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
databaseHandler.insertDays(String.valueOf(days));
```

to

```
databaseHandler.insertDays(days);
```

The first version converts your list to a `String` representation and calls a different `insertDays()` method than the one you have shown here.

Comment: Im getting this errror. `java.util.List.<java.lang.String> in DatabaseHandler cannot be applied to java.util.List<org.joda.time.LocalDate`

Comment: @Nube1Nu2 How do you declare `days`?

Comment: @Nube1Nu2 You can write a new `insertDays()` method which takes a `List<LocalDate>`. It will iterate through the list and convert each day to a string and then insert the string into the database.

Comment: days are declared button onClick

Comment: @Nube1Nu2 You should edit your question to show this declaration.